# Search array of objects, recent values missing/values reported as errors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects that and I'm looking to return the `timeStamp` values for each entry. The method I am using is below:

```
function popGraph() {
    jQuery(globalData).each(function(i, item) {
      console.log(item.uID, item.timeStamp) 
    });
}
```

However, it seems not be returning a large section of the most up to date data.  The most recent value returned is `timeStamp: 1484747211` but the most recent entry in the data is `timeStamp:14957862831`

The console also seems to be saying that each `console.log` is an error:

```
19455746_3_10 1483388143.76518  scripts.js:37:7
```

Example of the array:

```
[{"blobJson":"x","deviceMfg":10,"eventCode":1,"sensorClass":3,"sensorUUID":"19455746","timeStamp":1.495786283580328E9,"uID":"19455746_3_10"},
{"blobJson":"x","deviceMfg":10,"eventCode":1,"sensorClass":3,"sensorUUID":"19455746","timeStamp":1.495786282578029E9,"uID":"19455746_3_10"},
{"blobJson":"x","deviceMfg":10,"eventCode":1,"sensorClass":3,"sensorUUID":"19455746","timeStamp":1.495786281072998E9,"uID":"19455746_3_10"}]
```

Comment: Why the `jQuery(...)` part? Use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead -> `globalData.map(...)`

Comment: really i didn't get what is your problem

Comment: The problem is the most recent timestamp the function is returning is a few days before the actual most recent timestamp stored in the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working fiddle for you : https://jsfiddle.net/e17p6vqb/8/

```
function popGraph(o) {
    $.each(o,function(i, item) {
      if(i >= 50){
        return false;
      }
        console.log(item.uID, item.timeStamp);
    });
}

var tmp = [{blobJson:"x",deviceMfg:10,eventCode:1,sensorClass:3,sensorUUID:"19455746",timeStamp:1.495786283580328E9,uID:"19455746_3_10"}];


popGraph(tmp);
```

Comment: Is it possible to set a limit to how many results it returns? e.g. the first 50 timesStamps?

Comment: That's perfect, thank you! I'll accept your answer and leave mine up as information for anyone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
globalData.map(item => {
   return {"timeStamp": item.timeStamp, uID: item.uID}
});
```

Comment: I'm still having the problem where the most recent value returned is `timeStamp: 1484747211` but the most recent entry in the data is `timeStamp:14957862831`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my problem is that the FireFox log console is only set up to display 1000 lines of log by default. I'm returning over 1000 lines here which is why the most recent logs where missing.

For anyone else, type `about:config` into FireFox address bar and scroll down to `devtools.hud.loglimit.console` where you can edit the limit.